# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <recently read> \endtemplate...nothing written in error line

Tags: tables

Sir
I am getting this error.

paper.tex
40
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
 \endtemplate

l.40
 In line no. 40 Nothing is written still it is showing error.

I m also writing the code for table.

```
\begin{table}[h!]                 
\caption{Delay Comparison of Proposed and Existing Method}                
\begin{center}        
\begin{tabular} {| m{2cm} | m{3cm}| m{3cm} | m{3m} |}    
 \hline    
 Node & OLSR (Proposed Method) & AODV (Existing Method) & DSDV (Existing Method)  
   \tabularnewline    
 \hline    
35  & 801 & 952 &  2457 \tabularnewline    
 \hline    
45  & 522 & 861 &  24621 \tabularnewline    
 \hline    
55  & 391 & 878 &  1277 \tabularnewline        
 \hline    
65  & 290 & 581 &  1144 \tabularnewline    
 \hline    
75  & 338 & 595 &  2103 \tabularnewline    
\hline    
\end{tabular}    
\label{tab1}    
\end{center}\vs{-4mm}    
\end{table}
```

Please solve my problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe. The width of the last column is clearly wrong (3m?!) but with that fixed your example works when pasted into a basic document (with `tabularx` loaded). You need to provide a complete example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` or else it may be impossible to for anyone help further.

Comment: Please post full MWE for your input, I've changed to \begin{tabular} {| p{2cm} | p{3cm}| p{3cm} | p{3cm} |}    then, it's working fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Your problem come from the width of the last column `m{3m}` instead of `m{3cm}`.

However, I think you don't need to use fixed width columns: you can use a standard column type, and use the `\thead` command from `makecell`, which allows for a common formatting and line breaks in standard column types. In addition, I propose a second,more professional looking layout, with no vertical rules and the horizontal rules from `booktabs`, which have variable thickness and add some vertical padding around them:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \newcommand*{\nl}{\newline}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Delay Comparison of Proposed and Existing Method}
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular} {|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}| }}
 \hline
 Node & OLSR \nl (Proposed Method) & AODV \nl (Existing Method) & DSDV \nl (Existing Method)
 \\
 \hline
65 & 290 & 581 & 1144 \\
 \hline
75 & 338 & 595 & 2103 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Delay Comparison of Proposed and Existing Method}
\centering
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{tabular} {*{4}{c}}
 \toprule
 Node & \thead{OLSR\\ (Proposed\\ Method)} & \thead{AODV \\ (Existing\\ Method)} & \thead{DSDV \\ (Existing\\ Method)}
 \\
 \midrule
65 & 290 & 581 & 1144 \\
 \addlinespace
75 & 338 & 595 & 2103 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]